# How to input this type of Nonlinear ODE into Runge-Kutta

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, runge-kutta-methods

Say I have a differential equation, such as $$y'(t)+y'(t)^3 -t^5+350=0$$ with some initial condition. How can we take this nonlinear ODE and plug it into a system that runge-kutta can deal with? I only really have seen ways to do it when the ODE is of the form $y'(t)=F(y,t)$?

Another example would be something like $$y''(t)(1+y''(t)^3) -y'(t)+\cos(y(t))=0$$ which I would be confused with as well, considering I'm used to breaking down the system into $\textbf{y}'(t)=A\textbf{y(t)}$, where we have the standard breakdown $y=(t,y_1(t), y_2(t))$, where $y_1'(t)=y_2(t)$, $y_2'(t)=f(t,y_1,y_2)$, etc.,

Any suggestions or ideas? [I know Mathematica can do it, and we can force mathematica to use Classical RK-4 to solve it, which is the origin of this question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194409/numerical-solution-using-rk4-to-solve-nonlinear-ode#comment506833_194409)

Comment: Are you asking for code to do it? Or how to write the ODE as a system of first order DEs?

Comment: How to write these systems, in such a way that RK-4 can be applied. I've only seen RK4 with terms that don't have their highest order derivative to a power other than 1. For example, the equation $x''(t)+x(t)=0$ is easy to make into a system such that RK works on it. But with these non-linear terms, I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Just write the ODE as a [system of differential algebraic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential-algebraic_system_of_equations).

Comment: Ooh, I forgot those existed. Time to do some refreshing on those. Thanks!

Comment: All good. A quick Google search for 'runge kutta differential algebraic equations' yields many resources you can use. Also, if you can get your hands on it, 'Solving Ordinary Differential Equations II: Stiff and Differential-Algebraic Problems' by Hairer and Wanner explicitly goes through the application of RK schemes to DAEs. The book is quite dense mind you, but it is very good in terms of explaining what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way is to take the derivative of the equation (let's stay with the first example),
$$
y''(1+3y'^2)-5t^4=0\iff y''=\frac{5t^4}{1+3y'^2}
$$
which can be solved by the standard method of transforming into a first-order system and applying a Runge-Kutta method. The only detail open is the initial value for $y'$ which has to be chosen as (one of) the root(s) of the cubic polynomial $v+v^3-t_0^5+350$.

You get the typical problems of applying ODE methods to DAE, that is, the solution of the derived equation will have an increasing error in the original equation, the polynomial or non-linear equation for the initial value can have multiple solutions or no solution at all. Naive projection to the manifold defined by the original equation to remove the first problem can reduce the order of the numerical method.

Comment: Quick question, doesn't taking the derivative require that $y''$ exists? I suppose in the first example given, $y'$ is clearly continuous as it is equal to a continuous function, but what about if the derivative of the RHS failed to exist at a point or points? i.e $f(y') = \lvert t -1 \rvert$ or $f(y') = H(t-a)$ (maybe these aren't great examples, I just can't construct many functions off the top of my head where an issue might lie). Then all I can think of is that you must revert to solving a system of DAEs, however unseemly (though I'm certainly no expert in computational maths).

Comment: The problem is, if you get multiple solutions, you need to chose one. If there is some kind of continuity, this is easy. However at branch points that can fail. Having a direction provided by the next higher derivative gives a natural choice. In the first example, taking the derivative is no problem as long as at $t=1$ one does not reach a branching point. In the second example the continuity of the solutions of $f$ is violated at $t=a$, there is no natural root at $t=a+0$ to continue. So either none is permissible or all continuations are equally valid.